# Tabulator - override existing formatters

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am currently working on a Python web framework leveraging on the Js ecosystem to create interactive pages and I am wondering if there a way to create bespoke formatters doing some logic and then reusing within the Js existing ones.

I looked at the code and I managed to get the format factory and then to be able to change the cell CSS style but I am wondering if there is already something in place for this.

For information this is the code generated on Python which is injected in the tabulator bespoke formatter definitions:

```js
function(cell, formatterParams){ 
    const cssAttrs = formatterParams.css;
    var cell = cell.getTable().modules.format.getFormatter('%s').call(cell.getTable().modules.format, cell, formatterParams);
    let frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(cell).firstChild;

    Object.keys(cssAttrs).forEach(function(key){frag.style[key] = cssAttrs[key]}); 
        
    return frag; 
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you just want to create your own formatter. If that’s the case, this link has custom for matters after the built in ones. http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/format

Comment: Actually what I am doing here is more creating a formatter to "decorate" an existing one. The cell.getTable().modules.format.getFormatter('stars') will get the cell decorated by a built-in one.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here you can either use a [Custom Formatter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/format#format-custom) as nrayburn-tech mentions, which you then assign to a column definition.

```js
//define formatter outside of the table
var customFormatter = function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered){
    //cell - the cell component
    //formatterParams - parameters set for the column
    //onRendered - function to call when the formatter has been rendered

    return "Mr" + cell.getValue(); //return the contents of the cell;
};

//in the column definition
{title:"Name", field:"name", formatter:customFormatter}
```

The other option is to extend the format module, either adding your own formatter or replacing an existing one with your own. Details of how to do this are explained in the [Module Extension Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/modules#module-format)

For example to add a new file formatter you would insert this code before instatiating your table:

```js
Tabulator.prototype.extendModule("format", "formatters", {
    file:function(cell, formatterParams){
        return "<img class='fileicon' src='/images/fileicons/" + cell.getValue() + ".png'></img>";
    },
});
```

You could then access the formatter in the column definition like so:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    columns:[
        {field:"Photo", title:"photo", formatter:"file"},
    ],
});
```

The same logic holds of overriding an existing formatter, simply define the formatter against its current name in the ***extendModule*** function and it will replace the built in formatter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but exactly as Kem mention, if I take your example and you added a File formatter with some complex logic and if I do not want to override your code but just for example change the CSS style or some attributes what should be the right way to wrap the existing File formatter ?

In my example I managed to do it by retrieving the .modules.format from the table static definition but I am just wondering if this something common. Personally I am not a big fan of fully replacing something well done to just add a tiny thing.

Comment: For information we used to create editors and formatter we have grouped some Tabulator extensions for our Epyk users here https://github.com/epykure/tabulator-extensions that we will propose soon (once the scope is complete) to the Tabulator team